# Build failed running pavelib.assets.update_assets: Subprocess return code: 1

Tags: python, django, openedx

```
   /bin/cp -rf node_modules/which-country/index.js
   common/static/common/js/vendor /bin/cp -rf
   node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon.js common/static/common/js/vendor
   /bin/cp -rf node_modules/squirejs/src/Squire.js
   common/static/common/js/vendor
   ---> pavelib.assets.webpack python manage.py lms --settings=devstack print_setting STATIC_ROOT 2>/dev/null
```

Build failed running pavelib.assets.update_assets: Subprocess return
   code: 1

Comment: Can you add description and your question with proper explanation?

Comment: @Anmol getting this error when running make dev.provision on devstack openedx . you can check exact error here https://github.com/regisb/openedx-docker/issues/24

Comment: There may be a few reasons mostly lower memory. And if you use custom themes then check COMPREHENSIVE_THEME_DIRS paths. And check the logs also